# Get Prisma response type from a FindUnique

Tags: typescript, next.js, types, prisma

Basically I'm trying to extract the type of a result of a `FindUnique` on Prisma, because the type it's returning is `any`:

```
import prisma from "@/libs/prismaDb";
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

export default async function getOrderById(orderId: string) {
  try {
    const order = await prisma.order.findUnique({
      where: { id: orderId },
      include: { address: {}, products: {} },
    });

    return order;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}

export type OrderByIdQueryResult = Prisma.PromiseReturnType<
  typeof getOrderById
>;
```

I've already tried to add the `findUniqueOrThrow` but it returns the type `$Result.GetResult<Prisma.$OrderPayload<ExtArgs>, T, "findUniqueOrThrow">` that still doesn't do the linting of the `order` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my code was correct, but it was an issue that happened after I've updated to the last prisma/prisma-client version, to fix this just write this on the terminal:

```
npm install prisma@5.9.1-dev.1 --save-dev
npm install @prisma/client@5.9.1-dev.1
```

Then generate prisma client again:

```
npx prisma generate
```